# `new Function` for json reference

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, json

I have JSON with references to other parts in that JSON file.

```js
// the function I would like to be reviewed
function referenceToObject(json, reference){
    return (new Function(
            'json', 'return json' + reference
    ))(json);
}

// json
var example = {
    "target": "['first']['second']",
    "first": {
        second: 'hi'
    }
};

// execution
console.log(referenceToObject(example, example.target));
```

That function basically executes like this:

```
return json['one']['two'];
```

Is there a better way to extract the `JSON` reference? I'm able to change every bit of this code, as well as the `JSON` because we are reworking the front- and the backend. So, if you have ideas to improve the `JSON` instead of the `Javascript` that would also be great.

Comment: Any reason why `target` is formatted in that way?

Comment: @DavidFoerster @josephthedreamer I can change the Target, is it best to use `reduce` there to get the location returned (just learned that function) or should I use a different approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you control over the value of the `target` attribute, I suggest to store the reference chain as a list of attribute names. Then you can easily resolve the reference without having to resort to `eval`-like meta-programming. A reduction would be ideal like you mentioned.

```js
function referenceToObject(json, target)
{
 if (target === undefined)
  target = json.target;

 return target.reduce(referenceToObject.reductor, json);
}

referenceToObject.reductor = function(obj, attrib)
{
 return obj[attrib];
};


var example = {
 "target": ['first', 'second'],
 "first": {
  second: 'hi'
 }
};

console.log(referenceToObject(example));
```